# Checkbox in label tag : Different result in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label for="checkbox2" id="label1">
    click <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" id="checkbox2"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').click(function(event) {
        $('#checkbox2').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    });
});
```

There's two checkboxes in the page. (#checkbox1, #checkbox2)
#checkbox1 is in label tag, and #checkbox2 is not.
I want to enable/disable #checkbox2 depending on #checkbox1.

- checked #checkbox1 -> enable #checkbox2
- unchecked #checkbox1 -> disable #checkbox2

When I check #checkbox1, #checkbox2 is enabled properly.
But #checkbox2 is checked simultaneously in Firefox only. (IE and Chrome is not)

I think the problem is related to ordering of events. But, I don't know exactly.

http://jsfiddle.net/vtLzj/2/

edited:

- I want to change the status of #checkbox2 after it is enabled only.
- I want to preserve the event of #label1 when #checkbox2 is enabled. (like Chrome or IE)
- Please test [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vtLzj/2/) with both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `for` attribute, and change the event listener from `click` to `change`.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my post. I want to change the status of #checkbox2 after it is enabled only.

Comment: Is there other solutions?

Comment: Why do you need another solution? The reason Firefox is checking the other box is because you set a bad `for` attribute on your label - a label that contains a checkbox and also references another box with `for` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay. I understand. I tested my code with Chrome first, so I thought the "undefined behaviour" is normal. Thanks, Niet.

Answer (score 0):

The `label` elements `for` attribute must be attached to the `checkbox1` element, but you can change the checked state of checkbox2 in the change handler of checkbox1

```
<label for="checkbox1" id="label1">click
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" id="checkbox2" />
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkbox1').change(function (event) {
        $('#checkbox2').prop({
            disabled: !this.checked,
            checked: this.checked
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hnb7F/)

Comment: I checked the demo. But, I want to preserve the event of #label1 when #checkbox2 is enabled. (like Chrome or IE)